# How do I dynamically assign the Model for a .find in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic

I am trying to create a Single Table Inheritance.

However, the Controller must be able to know which class to find or create.  These are based on another class.

For example, ContactEvent with type = Letter needs to grab attributes from a corresponding Model called Letter.

Here's what I've tried to do and hit a snag, labelled below.

I need to be able to dynamically call assign a value of EventClass so that it can be Letter.find(:conditions =>) or Calls.find(:conditions =>) depending on which type the controller is acting on.

```
  def new
    @contact_event = ContactEvent.new
    @contact_event.type = params[:event_type] # can be letter, call, postcard, email
    @contact_event.event_id = params[:event_id] # that ID to the corresponding Model
    @contact_event.contact_id = params[:contact]

    @EventClass = case
      when @contact_event.type == 'letter' then 'Letter'
      when @contact_event.type == 'call' then 'Call'
      when @contact_event.type == 'email' then 'Email'
```

#### SNAG BELOW:

```
    @event = @EventClass.find(@contact_letter.letter_id) #how do I make @EventClass actually the Class?SNAG

    # substitution of variables into the body of the contact_event
    @event.body.gsub!("{FirstName}", @contact.first_name)
    @event.body.gsub!("{Company}", @contact.company_name) 
    @evebt.body.gsub!("{Colleagues}", @colleagues.to_sentence)

    @contact_event.body = @event.body
    @contact_event.status = "sent"

  end
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@event_class = case @contact_event.type
  when 'letter' then Letter
  when 'email'  then Email
  when 'call'   then Call
end
```

You have to assign the class itself, not a string. You can then just call `@event_class.find(whatever)`. Some things to note:

Single table inheritance is supported, and handled automatically by Rails. You can have Letter, Email and Call inherit from ContactEvent. Read more at [Rails API](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html) (section Single Table Inheritance)

You can convert your string directly by calling `@contact_event_type.classify.constantize` (this turns "call" into Call, for example).

Also, try to name your variables according to ruby conventions (@event_type instead of @EventType), and check your use of the case statement.

Hope it's useful :)

Comment: Hi, thanks, I did read the Single Table INheritance an dit is supported...but I thought only if you call out the sub-classes specifically....but seems like I still need to identify what that is....?  Or can I use .class method and pass it thorugh?  Is there a way for me to *not* have to you the :type variable passed through?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what your schema is. Are email, call and letter subtypes of ContactEvent (which seems the more logical to me)?

If so, I think you cannot escape passing the parameter (or call different URLs), and in your controller you'd just call `@event_class.new`, since the @even_class variable holds the class itself (remember, in Ruby, classes are objects **too**)

Comment: Actual, ContactEmail, ContactCall and ContactLetter at the subtype of ContactEvent.

A ContactEmail however, is instantiated with Email.id of whatever instance of Email is passed into it.  Think of Email as a template, and ContactEmail is the execution of Email with a specific Contact.

Answer (score 12):

This should allow you to dynamically call a model, an example with a User model:

```
model = "user".capitalize.constantize
model.all
```

Example of usage:

```
model = params[:object_type].capitalize.constantize
if model.destroy_all(params[:object_id])
  render :json => { :success => true }
else
  render :nothing => true
end
```

Comment: Actually dynamic and one line to boot.

Comment: Are there any negative consequences that may be introduced with this?